# Using Multiple AddWsFederation() in Multi-Tenant Environment

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I have searched but have been unable to find any documentation regarding the use of multiple `.AddWsFederation` extensions.

I currently do not have two AD instances setup in order to test, so I was simply wondering if anyone is familiar with the concept of adding *more than one* `.AddWsFederation` extensions within a single app.

**The idea is to allow the users of my multi-tenant application to login via their own Azure Active Directory instances.** *User A* who belongs to *Tenant A* would login via their own Azure AD instance while *User B* who belongs to *Tenant B* would login via their own Azure AD instance.

Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is any documentation on this?

```
    services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddWsFederation(options =>
    {
        // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
        options.MetadataAddress = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/.../federationmetadata.xml";

        // Wtrealm is the app's identifier in the Active Directory instance.
        // For ADFS, use the relying party's identifier, its WS-Federation Passive protocol URL.
        // For AAD, use the App ID URI from the app registration's Properties blade.
        // Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation
        options.Wtrealm = Configuration["WtRealm"];
    });
```

**Edit:** The application currently uses a mix of ASPNET Core Identity authentication as well as providing login via a single WsFederation instance (shown above):

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 10;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Well, I can say it is possible. You do have to give a name to each authentication scheme that you add. Do you have cookie authentication or similar as well for local authentication state?

Comment: One question of course is how you will detect which scheme to use when login is required. You can use subdomains for this purpose if you setup one for each tenant.

Comment: Thanks - I am currently using subdomains but how can I name the WsFederations differently?  Is it the DisplayName? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.wsfederationextensions.addwsfederation?view=aspnetcore-2.2?  Yes, the application also supports local accounts ASP.NET Core Identity (does that answer your question?).

Comment: Should be this overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.wsfederationextensions.addwsfederation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_WsFederationExtensions_AddWsFederation_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationBuilder_System_String_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_WsFederation_WsFederationOptions__

Comment: No, I mean is it the WS-Fed scheme that sets up the local auth state (cookie or otherwise), or is cookie authentication or something else used in addition. The reason I ask is to know if you can setup default signin schemes etc.

Comment: OK great, so I would want to give each instance it's own authentication scheme name (and I assume this can be anything I want to call it?).  I believe I am using Identity for local authentication state and simply using WsFederation to allow users another means of singing in.  Upon initial sign in via Azure AD, a local account is created in the application database.  I hope this answers your question!  (I also updated the question, by the way.)  Thanks.

Comment: That actually does help :) Then you can setup default schemes to Identity. But, you'll want to somehow setup a ForwardChallengeSelector on the identity scheme. In this lambda, you can check the hostname and return the correct scheme's name for that subdomain. And yeah the names can be anything you want. They could be your tenant ids or subdomains or anything else. I haven't played around with Identity enough to know how the forward selector can be setup, but it should be possible somehow :)

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using the AAD multi-tenant app feature (support OIDC, not WSFed). That way your app just points to AAD Common endpoint and it does home realm discovery and re-direction to user's specific tenant. Your app has to acces or reject tokens based on which tenant issued them but it is a much simpler and more generic scheme than what you have with WSFed.

Comment: That's a great point - I should look into that and post an answer. 
 I am also open to any other answers if anyone has any code examples to share https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-handle-multiple-issuer-values